# Regular expression for phone number validation, number starting with 0 or + sign

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

Can anyone help me, i need a single regular expression for phone number validation which will accept either 0 or +

Comment: [This](http://gskinner.com/RegExr) is a good website for testing RegEx. Try it and post your results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following regex for that:

```
^[+0]\d+
```

Thanks

Comment: So that the number can start with either a leading `0` or a `+`

Comment: @Xmindz In this case the number may start either with leading `0`, `+`, or `,`. ;)

Answer (score 4):

```
[0+]\d{9}
```

and when you need that the whole string was equal to the number you must add `^` and `$`:

```
^[0+]\d{9}$
```

`[0+]` means `0` or `+`; `\d` means *any digit*; `{9}` means "repeated 9 times";
`^` means beginning of the line; ^$^ means end of the line.

Comment: What about the slashes?  I don't usually see that in .NET regexes.

Comment: @TimS.: You don't neet them, I used them just to say that it is a re.